# how do i turn this into a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to figure out how to convert this into list comprehension ---

```
temp = []
for data in current_set.data_set:
    if(data[0] == day and data[1] == time):
        #print(str(data[0]) + " , " + str(data[1]) + " , " + str(data[3]))
        temp.append(data[3])
```

Comment: I edited your question and changed the word "conversion" to "comprehension" which I think is what you meant. Change it back if you really meant "conversion."

Answer (score 4):

I believe you want a "list comprehension" (not a list *conversion*)--try this.

```
temp = [data[3] for data in current_set.data_set if data[0] == day and data[1] == time]
```

Or, if you want to avoid the long line (as you should):

```
temp = [data[3] for data in current_set.data_set
                if data[0] == day and data[1] == time]
```

But that is hard to check since you did not supply a full code snippet, including example data. This ignores the print statement you hid in a comment. You can see that practically everything in my statement comes from your code.

Answer (score -2):

If I follow, you just want to turn the array into a list?

`list(temp)` will give you a list

Comment: No, he's clearly got an `if` in there to filter out some of the values, and he also wants just `data[3]`, not the whole `data`.

Comment: Without knowing what `data` looks like, this question is ambiguous as it is. For all we know, data is a collection of 4 values and `data[3]` is just a simple integer or otherwise that is being appended to `temp`. Until more details are added/terminology corrected, this is somewhat of a toss up

Comment: No, the question may be incomplete, but it's not ambiguous, and certainly not in a way that could make this answer possibly sensible. It doesn't matter whether `data` is a list of 4 ints or a numpy array of 28 objects of which data[3] is a tuple of three files, it's still perfectly sensible to collect each `data[3]`, and the OP's code and Rory Daulton's code do that, while yours does something completely different.

Comment: Okay, well in the first situation, my solution worked. I know, I ran it. Had I known what data[3] looked like, I would have provided a different solution if needed

Comment: Well, yes, your solution does give you a list, but it doesn't give you a list anything like the one the OP is asking for. If all you want is just any list, you can just do `[]` and be done with it. The fact that you didn't read the OP's question doesn't make your answer more useful.